# Disable iOS and Android App from App store and google play store with custom message to users

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there a way to disable iOS and Android apps which are live, for a few hours and add some custom message to all users, Can this be done through itunesconnect for Apple or google developer console for andorid.

Note :- i dont want to release new Apps / change existing code.

max

Comment: Disable  means user can't use it? Or can't download it?

Comment: i mean disable means user cant use it, as soon as he opens it he will see the custom message and wont be able to use the app, for example :- we are temporarily unvailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned you don't want to release new apps or change existing code, but unfortunately for this level of customization you'll have to (to start!) There's no push of a button to do this for you for either dashboard.

There's multiple ways of doing this and there's no official documentation out there, so if this answer gets accepted by the OP still look around at other answers on this thread.

My approach is to listen to an endpoint that you create, may it be from dropbox, s3, parse, etc. that have certain key-value pairs that your application can retrieve and handle appropriately.  To the level of customization is up to you.

Let's do the example of your "we're temporarily unavailable" idea. Have the endpoint do the following:

```
{
   "unavailable" : false,
   "unavailable_text" : "Sorry we'll be back shortly!"
}
```

Now on app start up you listen to this endpoint.  One day the `unavailable` key will be true, when that happens in the success handler for the endpoint you'll put in some logic to present a `UnavailableViewController` of sorts that might have a `UILabel` called `descriptionLabel`

```
if ([json valueForKey:@"unavailable"]) {
    UnavailableViewController* controller = [[UnavailableViewController alloc] init];
    controller.descriptionLabel.text = ([json valueForKey:@"unavailable_text"]) ? [json valueForKey:@"unavailable_text"] : @"We're temporarily unavailable, please try again later."; // just in case you forget to set it have a fallback.
    // present view controller...
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know in comments of any questions/concerns.

Comment: my scenario is something where on my app start up the end point itself is down for maintanence, and thats the reason i want to populate this message to users from somewhere, and i was wondering in my case i have one option lef that could be itunes connect / google developer console. Any help on this ,

Comment: That is a tricky scenario!  Perhaps the end point when it fails for server maintenance can give a custom error code, such as 505, etc., or I guess 404 probably works.  I'm not a backend expert though so not sure what best practice is for error codes. But regardless the failure or completion block could listen for that error code and when found can bring up this view.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help me understand where would this completion block be placed and i could bring up this view, Note :- I am not looking for a code change or release a new app , My scenario is without touching the code or releasing a new app i would like to add this message to users

Comment: As mentioned in the answer this unfortunately will need a code change.  Apple nor Google provide this feature; if your app needs to handle server maintenance downtime it will require some customization on your end to display this content instead of looking broken, etc.